# WordPress Woocommerce update variation pricing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update the prices of my variations based on the zipcode.
I already have a popup and a custom webhook that saves the zipcode to the Woocommerce session. (`WC()->customer`)

I am able to print this zipcode using:  `$zipcode = WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode();`

On the backend of the product, in the variation editor I added a custom textfield called: `_zipcode_prices`
Here I want to define the prices that correspond with the zipcodes for example: 1020AA:80;2368PO:100 (zipcode:price).

I can get the zipcodes and prices from the variation using:

```
$zipcode_prices = get_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], '_zipcode_prices', true );

// Check if the zipcode prices are set for the variation
if ( $zipcode_prices ) {

    // Convert the zipcode prices into an array
    $zipcode_prices_array = explode(';', $zipcode_prices);

    // Loop through the array and find the price for the entered zipcode
    foreach ($zipcode_prices_array as $zipcode_price) {

        // Split the zipcode and price
        $zipcode_price_array = explode(':', $zipcode_price);

        // Check if the entered zipcode matches the zipcode in the array
        if ($zipcode_price_array[0] == $zipcode) {

        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that I can't figure out is how to update the prices on the frontend and make woocommerce use the correct prices based on the zip code.

What hook do I have to use to update the variation prices?